# create more on same page on clicked button

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have already created a widget (including text form) with the thing i want. Im currently displaying one on the page, but i want to add when another button is pressed add one more. I would like to have the text felts = to diffrent things so i can show both on another page.

This is my page created

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: CloseButton(),
          actions: buildEditingActions(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Text...",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
                buildTitle(),
                SizedBox(height: 12),
                buildDateTimePickers(),
                Text("\nText",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
                buildWidget(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

i want to be able to show the diffrent text input fields on another page, but starting with only one on the main page and everytime the button gets clicked it adds another text field, Anybody know how to do this?

I was thinking, to make a loop with a variable like in PHP "$NR" and set = 1 and then name the text fields something like "Text$NR" and at the end of the loop set $NR += 1 and then the amount of times looped is = the amount of time the button is pressed.
But im not quite sure if this would work

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Do you want to just have a button to add new Text Fields to the screen?

Because I can not understand this part in the question: " would like to have the text felts = to diffrent things so i can show both on another page."

Comment: i want to be able to show the diffrent text input fields on another page, but starting with only one on the main page and everytime the button gets clicked it adds another text field

Comment: When the user clicks the button, would it be added to the new page or to the current one?

Comment: the current one

Comment: Okay and what do you want to do for the new page?

Comment: On the new page i want to show the previus information that the user types in. All of the text bokses depending on how many times the user clicked on the button (to add new textfields) in the previus page

Comment: I just editet my current thoughts on how to do it, but im not sure if it would work or there is a easier way to do it. Im pretty new to flutter

Comment: Don't worry, I will help you achieving the intended logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Step:** Make sure that the screen holding text fields is a `StatefulWidget`.

**Second Step:** Declare an `int` variable to hold the count of text fields in the screen and start it with 1 (The initial text field), for example:

```
int numberOfTextFields = 1;
```

**Third Step:** In the code where you place your text fields, make a `for loop` with iterations equal to the value of the variable holding the count of text fields and render the text field widget, for example:

```
Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(
        children: [
            ...
            for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTextFields ; i++)
                TextField()
            ...
        ],
    ),
),
```

**Fourth Step:** In the callback of the button, increment the count variable inside `setState()` method, for example:

```
{
    ...
    setState((){
        numberOfTextFields++;
    })
    ...
}
```

**Lastly:** To get the values from the Text Fields and pass them to the new screen, you can follow any tutorial to know how to get a value from text field in flutter, and then pass them with the why you are using, for example, Passing them in the constructor of the new screen or passing them to the `arguments` parameter while using named routes.

Comment: Thank you so much :-) im gonna try this out first thing tomorrov. Gotta get up early 

Comment: One thing im thinking about is would the new textfield, since it have the same name, just replace the Old value?

Comment: Don't worry it is basic and feel free to ask any question ❤

Comment: No it would not replace it.

Comment: So how would i show it on another page if both text fields is named TextField()

Comment: TextField is the name of the class, and the `TextField()` is just an object from the class, you can instantiate any number of objects you want from the class.

To get the value from the text fields, follow a tutorial and you would find it basic, don't overthink it.

Comment: You are always welcome, and feel free to ask any further questions, and don't forget to vote up and accept the answer if it solved the problem ❤

Comment: Worked really well and as i wanted. but the text fields have the same value. I just commentet my new problem -_-

Comment: Kindly add the new problem as question with all the details and trials in order to better understand it. Don't forget to comment here with the link and I will help you ❤

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72575100/2-textfields-with-the-same-value
Here you go :-))

Answer (score 0):

The method works like a charm for creating extra fields. I'm having the problem that whatever I type in text field 1 automatically becomes the input in text field 2.

```
Widget buildSets() => TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
        ],
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Sets',
        ),
        onFieldSubmitted: (_) => saveForm,
        validator: (sets) =>
            sets != null && sets.isEmpty ? 'Sets cannot be empty' : null,
        controller: setsController,
      );
```

The way i store the information is in "sets" and if this was in like PHP i would say sets$numberOfTextFields to give them all a diffrent location to store. Im not quite sure how to do that in flutter and i tried the method with sets${numberOfTextFields}. but i dindt work