# 2 textfields with the same value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a code that creates a text field when a button is pushed. i got the problem that if you type something in text field 1 it automaticly is in text field 2 so i cant have 2 diffrent things

I have the following code

```
int numberOfTextFields = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: CloseButton(),
          actions: buildEditingActions(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTextFields ; i++) 
                buildExerciseComplete(),
                buildAddMore(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

with is a simple button and the buildsets() being this:

```
Widget buildSets() => TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
        ],
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Sets',
        ),
        onFieldSubmitted: (_) => saveForm,
        validator: (sets) =>
            sets != null && sets.isEmpty ? 'Sets cannot be empty' : null,
        controller: setsController,
      );
```

and this is the button:

```
Widget buildAddMore() => ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState((){
        numberOfTextFields++;
    });
            },
            child: Text('Add new exercise'),  
          );
```

The way i store the information is in "sets" and if this was in like PHP i would say sets$numberOfTextFields to give them all a diffrent location to store. Im not quite sure how to do that in flutter and i tried the method with sets${numberOfTextFields}. but i dindt work

My code up here is a bit i a bit simplyfied. My real code looks like this: The problem is that the two diffrent fiels always have the same values
[Picture of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YotO.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'utils.dart';
import 'event_provider.dart';

class EventEditingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Event? event;

  const EventEditingPage({Key? key, this.event}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EventEditingPageState createState() => _EventEditingPageState();
}

class _EventEditingPageState extends State<EventEditingPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final setsController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      final event = widget.event!;

      setsController.text = event.Sets;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    setsController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
int numberOfTextFields = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: CloseButton(),
          actions: buildEditingActions(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTextFields ; i++) 
                buildExerciseComplete(),
                buildAddMore(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
     

  List<Widget> buildEditingActions() => [
        ElevatedButton.icon(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.transparent, shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
          onPressed: saveForm,
          icon: Icon(Icons.done),
          label: Text('Save'),
        )
      ];

 
  Widget buildExerciseComplete() => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 200, 200),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          border: Border.all(
            width: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
        height: 50,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                 Expanded(child: buildSets()),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Widget buildSets() => TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
        ],
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Sets',
        ),
        onFieldSubmitted: (_) => saveForm,
        validator: (sets) =>
            sets != null && sets.isEmpty ? 'Sets cannot be empty' : null,
        controller: setsController,
      );

  
  Widget buildAddMore() => ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState((){
        numberOfTextFields++;
    });
            },
            child: Text('Add new exercise'),  
          );
        
  

  


  Future saveForm() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();

    if (isValid) {
      final event = Event(
          Sets: setsController.text);

      
class Event {
  final String Sets;
  final Color backgroundColor;


  const Event({
    required this.Sets,
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you include full widget ?

Comment: i have included the button widget now, if thats what you ment :)

Comment: Can you include full  widget that will reproduce the same issue.? You can find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: On your single row, you are having 3 textFiled ?

Comment: Yes i have, i have just uploaded the code that should reproduce the problem, this is only with one text field just to try to minimize it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same `TextEditingController()` with all the Text Fields, you have to create a controller for each one, you can do the following:

**Step 1:** Remove the currently used `TextEditingController` logic.

**Step 2:** In the screen containing the variable named `numberOfTextFields`, define a List of `TextEditingController` and start it with a controller inside:

```
List<TextEditingController> _textEditingControllers = [TextEditingController()];
```

**Step 3:** In add more function, when you increment the `numberOfTextFields` variable, add a new controller to the list:

```
onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
        numberOfTextFields++;
        _textEditingControllers.add(TextEditingController());
    });
},
```

**Step 4:** Inside the loop when you create the Text Fields based on the value of the variable `numberOfTextFields`, pass the controller that corresponds the value of the loop counter `i` to the widget from the list:

```
children: [
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTextFields ; i ++) 
        buildExerciseComplete(controller: _textEditingControllers[i]),
        buildAddMore(),
],
```

*Note that the `TextFormField` is already nested in some widgets, then you have to pass the controller to the widget until you reach the `TextFormField`.

**Step 5:** In the screen where you declared the `_textEditingControllers` list, dispose all the controllers in the list in dispose method:

```
@override
void dispose() {
    for (TextEditingController controller in _textEditingControllers)
    {
        controller.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
}
```

**That's It!**

Comment: and change dispose to: for (TextEditingController controller in _textEditingControllers) { controller.dispose();} super.dispose();

Comment: @mohamed.oussous Thanks, I will add it to the answer.

Comment: at the "buildExerciseComplete(controller: _textEditingControllers[i])," i get an error saying i havent defined controller

Comment: Yes you have to define it as a parameter to the function and pass it until you reach the `TextFormFileld`

Comment: You are always welcome ❤

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `controller: setsController` for every textfield in your loop is the cause of your issue, setting the same TextEditingController for multiple TextField will lead to have the same thing you type in all the textFields that shares the same controller, to solve this issue, you need to initialize a TextEditingController for every TextField

---

**UPDATE:**
To set a different controller for each field, you have to create a `List<TextEditingController>` and it must be the same size of your `numberOfTextFields`, pass the controller or the index to your method:

```
Widget buildSets(final TextEditingController controller) => TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
    ],
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'Sets',
    ),
    onFieldSubmitted: (_) => saveForm,
    validator: (sets) =>
        sets != null && sets.isEmpty ? 'Sets cannot be empty' : null,
    controller: controller,
  );
  //Calling the method:
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTextFields ; i++) 
      buildSets(myControllers[i]),
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how i can give them diffrent controllers when im creating multiple in a loop?

Comment: change the buildSets funtion to StatefulWidget and add the controller there

Answer (score 1):

Create separate respective controller for each field.
You can use `List<TextEditingController> controllers` to store controllers in it and with each iteration of the loop, you can use `controllers.add` method to add a controller with `controllers[i].text = '$i'`. And set the controller in textField like this: `controller: controllers['i']`.