# How to use different text editing controllers when creating text forms dynamically in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, controller

I am creating multiple textfields with a button click using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72566552/14554403

```
int numberOfTextFields = 0;
```

```
Column(
  children: [
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTextFields ; i++)
     TextField(
            controller: _extraNumberController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Number',
            )),
  ],
),
```

The method works like a charm for creating extra fields. I'm having the problem that whatever I type in text field 1 automatically becomes the input in next text field. This happens because I am using the same controller for every fields.

How to use different controllers for each textfield that will be generated?

Comment: Where are u instantiating `_extraNumberController`? Please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

> This happens because I am using the same controller for every fields.

The answer is hidden in your question. You need to provide a new instance of '_extraNumberController' instead of the same each time.

In order to achieve that, you may create a method e.g., `getExtraNumberController()` that returns a new instance of `_extraNumberController` and use it in your code as follows:

```
Column(
  children: [
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numberOfTextFields ; i++)
     TextField(
            controller: getExtraNumberController(),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Number',
            )),
  ],
),
```